# rails s: Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: rubygems, rake, rvm

When I start rails with:

```
$ rails s
```

I get:

```
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

So, I ran `bundle install`:

```
$ bundle install
Using rake 10.4.2
```

but `gem list rake` gives:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rake (10.1.0, 10.0.4)
```

How come I don't have `rake 10.4.2` installed?

Also, when I run `bundle check` it gives me:

```
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
```

which does not seem to be correct. Why?

==== UPDATE

I fixed the problem with `rake` by doing:

```
gem install rake
```

but why did I have to install it manually? I thought that was Bundler's job.

And trying to start rails again gave me another problem:

```
Could not find multi_json-1.10.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

Clearly there's some underlying problem here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this problem using rbenv for my ruby 2.2.0 install. Fixed through trial and error.

I tried doing `gem install rake` but this didn't fix it. 
So I did:

```
gem uninstall rake
rbenv global 2.1.1
rbenv rehash
rbenv uninstall rake #this time gives error "rake is a default gem"
rbenv global 2.2.0
rbenv rehash
gem install rake
rails s #works this time
```

My expectation is that there was maybe a conflict somewhere in PATH or similar that was resolved with a complete remove

I've had that error with multi_json before. Fixed it by doing manual install `gem install multi_json`

Answer (score 9):

I think your gems bundled with project (BUNDLED_PATH defined in projects .bundle/config).

If you need to run bundled version of rails server, you must type in console

```
bundle exec rails s
```

Or, alternatively, you can generate bin stubs of bundled gem commads by

```
bundle --binstubs
```

and run generated stub

```
bin/rails s
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed only to correct the `enable` script.

```
cd /opt/rh/ruby-22
rpm -q -f enable
rh-ruby22-runtime-2.0-6.el6.x86_64
diff enable~ enable
1c1
< export PATH=/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
---
> export PATH=/opt/rh/ruby/root/usr/local/bin/:/opt/rh/rh-ruby22/root/usr/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
scl enable rh-ruby22 bash
```

http://www.softwarecollections.org/

Answer (score -3):

```
cd /usr/share/metasploit-framework/
```

Then use the following command

```
bundle install
```