# Why doesn't "bundle exec" see that I have rake installed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, bundler, rbenv

I've been reading StackOverflow and trying to deal with this error for 2 hours now:

```bash
bundle exec rake db:setup
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I followed the advice here, to no avail:

[rails s: Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879119/rails-s-could-not-find-rake-10-4-2-in-any-of-the-sources-bundlergemnotfound)

also:

[Could not find rake with bundle exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978002/could-not-find-rake-with-bundle-exec)

So I did:

```bash
gem uninstall rake
gem install rake
```

And, following the other StackOverflow articles I read, I tried:

```bash
rbenv install 2.3.1                   
Downloading ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.1.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.3.1...
Installed ruby-2.3.1 to /Users/lkrubner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1

rbenv global 2.3.1
ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]

bundle exec rake db:setup
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

rbenv rehash
rbenv uninstall rake
rbenv: version `rake' not installed
```

At the command line, if I look for versions, I see:

```bash
rake -V
rake, version 11.2.2

rails -v
Rails 4.2.0

ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
```

but I still get this error:

```bash
bundle exec rake db:setup   
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

What would fix this?

### Update 1

This is even more confusing:

```bash
bundle update rake

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Installing rake 11.2.2 (was 10.4.2)
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.0
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.4
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.0
Using rack 1.6.4
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.0
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activejob 4.2.0
Using mime-types 2.99
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.0
Using activemodel 4.2.0
Using arel 6.0.3
Using activerecord 4.2.0
Using addressable 2.3.8
Using multi_xml 0.5.5
Using httparty 0.13.7
Using uuidtools 2.1.5
Using aws-sdk 1.3.9
Using bcrypt 3.1.10
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using bson 3.2.6
Using bson_ext 1.5.1
Using bundler 1.8.5
Using byebug 8.2.1
Using xpath 2.0.0
Using capybara 2.5.0
Using ffi 1.9.10
Using childprocess 0.5.8
Using climate_control 0.0.3
Using cocaine 0.5.8
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.6.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using database_cleaner 1.5.1
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using responders 2.1.0
Using warden 1.2.3
Using devise 3.5.2
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using dotenv 2.1.0
Using dotenv-rails 2.1.0
Using factory_girl 4.5.0
Using factory_girl_rails 4.5.0
Using faker 1.4.3
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using faraday 0.9.2
Using sass 3.4.19
Using foundation-rails 5.5.3.2
Using geocoder 1.2.9
Using httpclient 2.6.0.1
Using icalendar 2.3.0
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using jbuilder 2.3.2
Using jquery-rails 4.0.5
Using jwt 1.5.2
Using kgio 2.9.3
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using mimemagic 0.3.0
Using mongo 2.1.2
Using origin 2.1.1
Using mongoid 5.0.1
Using paperclip 4.3.2
Using mongoid-paperclip 0.0.10
Using oauth2 1.0.0
Using slop 3.6.0
Using pry 0.10.1
Using pry-rails 0.3.4
Using quiet_assets 1.1.0
Using sprockets 3.4.1
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.3
Using rails 4.2.0
Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
Using raindrops 0.15.0
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using rspec-support 3.3.0
Using rspec-core 3.3.1
Using rspec-expectations 3.3.0
Using rspec-mocks 3.3.1
Using rspec-rails 3.3.2
Using rspec_junit_formatter 0.2.2
Using rubyzip 1.1.7
Using tilt 2.0.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.4
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using websocket 1.2.2
Using selenium-webdriver 2.48.1
Using shoulda-matchers 2.8.0
Using signet 0.7.2
Using simple_form 3.2.0
Using spring 1.4.4
Using timezone 0.5.0
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using uglifier 2.7.2
Using unicorn 4.9.0
Using web-console 2.2.1
Updating files in vendor/cache
  * rake-11.2.2.gem
Removing outdated .gem files from vendor/cache
  * rake-10.4.2.gem
Bundle updated!
 bundle exec rake db:setup
Could not find rake-11.2.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
 bundle update rake
```

So one line says that rake is installed, and the next line says that it is not installed, and both lines are nominally being managed by Bundler, so in theory this can not be a cache problem.

### Update 2

I added this to the Gem file:

```bash
gem 'rake', '10.5.0'
```

And then ran

```bash
bundle install
```

which gives me:

```bash
Updating files in vendor/cache
Bundle complete! 40 Gemfile dependencies, 116 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/cache.
```

So then I try:

```bash
bundle exec rake db:setup
```

and I get:

```
Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Comment: Did you try `bundle install`?

Comment: Can you paste the output of `which rbenv` here?

Comment: Yes, of course I've run "bundle install". Many times.

Comment: lle Eftimov -- the output of "which rbenv" is: /usr/local/bin/rbenv

Comment: Deleting .bash_profile and .bashrc and .zshrc and reinstalling ruby and rails and rbenv -- this seemed to help slightly. I've got a different error now.

Comment: @charlottesville Are you deploying or trying to get up and running in development?

Answer (score -2):

You *could* try to run install command as *`sudo`* and specify `rake`'s version like this:

```bash
sudo gem install rake -v '11.2.2'
```

Comment: You should never run `gem` with `sudo`, it messes up permissions and will bite you in the future. More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119064/sudo-gem-install-or-gem-install-and-gem-locations